# Hibernate StandardServiceRegistryImpl doesn't use default dialect settings

Tags: hibernate, service, settings, default

After migration to Hibernate 4 I realized that the our batching is not working because **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size** is not set.

When the *BatchBuilderImpl* is configured, it receives configuration values that contain only environment settings and explicitly configured options from persistence.xml

Quick fix is to explicitly declare **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size** (>1)

Question is, why the *StandardServiceRegistry* that configures all services including *BatchBuilderImpl*, doesn't use *Settings* built by *SettingsFactory* which include dialect defaults (including **hibernate.jdbc.batch_size**)